# Meteor modularity and access protection — is everything 'global'?

Tags: javascript, python, oop, meteor, modularity

I'm exploring Meteor and I'm trying to understand how it works, modularity-wise, compared to other more OOP systems I'm more familiar with, such as Python.

It seemed to me that breaking things into separate files — HTML templates, corresponding JS files — was fairly arbitrary and corresponded only to the organization in the programmer's mind.  Is there something more to it?

As I understand it, all the javascript is joined together, all the HTML, all the CSS, all the templates.

Is there any sense of the kind of protection that one would get with Python modules, with OOP classes?  I know that whether one declares a variable in a Meteor JS file with a 'var' or not determines whether it has global access — how does one use this to 'modularize' the app, if all the Javascript files are joined together (if they *are* in fact joined together)?

Forgive my ulta-newbie question — but if you have any insight on how to see the forest for the trees, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Peppe's answer, the same thing happens on the server.

If you want to declare something as global, omit the `var` when declaring the variable:

```
some_global_thing = {}
```

This will add that to `window` (or `global` if the code is on the server) object, which will make it globally available.

The same thing runs for functions. Think about this:

```
function my_fn() {}
```

will be sent as:

```
(function(){
    alert("This is file 2.")
})()
```

So, to make them globally available you have to declare them as:

```
my_fn = function() {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd read that. How would one use this fact to modularize the code? I suppose the obvious thing is that each file exists pretty much in its own space, not polluting the global space. Other than things interacting through globals how do they?  I may be missing the forest for the trees but coming from an oop background where a imports b and has access to a few public methods I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Cerulean, there only exists two namespaces: the "file name space" (use `var`) and "the global namespace" (omit `var`). A third option is creating a package. The namespaces in packages works the same way, but you decide which global variables should be visible for the applications using your package.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the files are joined together into one big file sent to the client, but the code in each file is put into a function directly called:

Your file1.js:

```js
alert("This is file 1.")
```

Your file2.js:

```
alert("This is file 2.")
```

What is sent to the client:

```
(function(){
    alert("This is file 1.")
})()

(function(){
    alert("This is file 2.")
})()
```

So local variables in the files wont effect each other, since they're local to the functions.